# How to append JSX to DOM in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dom

I want to append something to my DOM.

```
let parent = document.getElementById("TabContainer");
let settings = 
<Box id="test">
  <GlobalSettings activeTab={"test"}></GlobalSettings>
</Box>
                
parent.appendChild(settings);
```

I get the following error

```
Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node'.
  Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'Node': baseURI, childNodes, firstChild, isConnected, and 47 more.
```

Box is a normal div and GlobalSettings is my own component.
I know it's maybe bad practice to manipulate the DOM like this, but for me it seems to be an easy way.
Btw this code runs in the onClick function from a Button.

I hope someone can help me :)

Thx

Answer (score 2):

JSX is only syntactic sugar; despite its appearance, it's not HTML, it's JavaScript. You can "append" something into your DOM using [ReactDOM.render](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render).

Edit: you're probably better off using [portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html); this is exactly what they are for.

Answer (score 2):

**React 18** warns that you need to use createRoot instead.

You can fix it by replacing ReactDom.render with this:

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

createRoot(parent).render(settings)
```